# Disable mouse wheel click / always have auto scroll work on Firefox

Tags: firefox

I have autoscroll setting enabled on Firefox. Whenever I press and hold the mouse wheel depressed, then move my mouse, the page scrolls up or down at a steady rate.

This doesn't work if I depress the mouse wheel overtop of a link. In this case no scrolling occurs, and it instead clicks the link. This seems sort of silly, as I already have my primary left mouse button for clicking links.

Ideally, press middle mouse button would be for only auto scrolling, and would work regardless of where on the page the cursor is, or what is specifically under it.

Is this somehow doable in Firefox?

Comment: "Whenever I press and hold the mouse wheel?" The mouse wheel simply has to be clicked *once* over a *blank spot* on the page. There's no need to *hold it down*. Move the mouse slightly up or down to control speed and direction of scroll.

Comment: Good point. Problem is still the same though. Regardless you can hold it down, and don't have to click again to release, which is the better way of doing it.